# Moving large set of points to new lat/long using python in field calculator - ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm using ArcMap 10.6.1. I have a large set of points I am trying to move to a new Lat/Long based off of two new fields (X2 and Y2) joined from another table. I have been researching this question for a few days and can't quite locate what I'm looking for. I've determined from others who have asked the questions that I need to use the Point function from the geometry classs in field calculator to do so. Currently I am receiving errors every time I try and run it. I am in an editing session.

[image: How I am currently trying to run it.]

Do I need to incorporate the codeblock into this?

I am also worried that I shouldn't be calling "arcpy" out, but I have tried it without the module and still getting errors.

Comment: Please do not add an answer to the Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach does not appear to work with joined data. What you can do is permanently join the XY fields to the featureclass using Join Field tool then run your expression as shown in your screenshot and that will move the geometry to the new location defined by the XY fields.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even consider that. By using the "Join Field" tool it worked! Thanks for your help!